# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: datatables and nuxt js

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, nuxt.js, web-deployment

I'm developing an admin panel with "**SCUTUM**" admin template with **nuxt.js**.
When I trying to use datatables component in the template it gives following error in the console. Component is made by template provider. And I used it as the example given by them.

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function Datatable() {
  return Promise.all(/*! import() */[__webpack_require__.e(0), __webpack_require__.e(1)]).then(__webpack_require__.bind(null, /*! ~/components/datatables/Datatables */ "./components/datatables/Datatables.vue"));
}
Reason: TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined
```

What is the reason for this?

Here is my code

```js
<template>
    <div id="sc-page-wrapper">
        <div id="sc-page-content">
            <ScCard class="">
                <ScCardHeader seperator>
                    <div class="uk-flex-middle uk-grid-small uk-grid" data-uk-grid>
                        <div class="uk-flex-1">
                            <ScCardTitle>
                                List of Lecturers
                            </ScCardTitle>
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-width-auto@s">
                            <div id="sc-dt-buttons"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ScCardHeader>
                <ScCardBody>
                    <client-only>
                        <Datatable
                            id="sc-dt-buttons-table"
                            ref="buttonsTable"
                            :data="dtDData"
                            :options="dtDOptions"
                            :buttons="true"
                            @initComplete="dtButtonsInitialized"
                        />
                    </client-only>
                </ScCardBody>
            </ScCard>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
const rows = require('~/data/pages/datatables.json');
import ScCard from "@/components/card/";
import {ScCardTitle, ScCardBody, ScCardHeader} from "@/components/card"
export default {
    name: 'Lecturer',
    components: {
        Datatable: () => import('~/components/datatables/Datatables'),
        ScCard,
        ScCardTitle,
        ScCardHeader,
        ScCardBody
    },
    data: () => ({
        dtDData: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows)),
        dtDOptions: {
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: "copyHtml5",
                    className: "sc-button",
                    text: 'Copy'
                },
                {
                    extend: "csvHtml5",
                    className: "sc-button",
                    text: 'CSV '
                },
                {
                    extend: "excelHtml5",
                    className: "sc-button",
                    text: 'Excel '
                },
                {
                    extend: "pdfHtml5",
                    className: "sc-button sc-button-icon",
                    text: '<i class="mdi mdi-file-pdf md-color-red-800"></i>'
                },
                {
                    extend: "print",
                    className: "sc-button sc-button-icon",
                    text: '<i class="mdi mdi-printer"></i>',
                    title: 'Custom Title',
                    messageTop: 'Custom message on the top',
                    messageBottom: 'Custom message on the bottom',
                    autoPrint: true
                }
            ]
        }
    }),
    mounted () {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            
        })
    },

    methods: {
        dtButtonsInitialized () {
            // append buttons to custom container
            this.$refs.buttonsTable.$dt.buttons().container().appendTo(document.getElementById('sc-dt-buttons'))
        },
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

Here is the Datatables component

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <table :id="id" class="uk-table uk-table-striped uk-table-middle" :class="[tableClass]" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th v-for="header in headers" :key="header" class="uk-text-nowrap">
                        {{ header }}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <slot name="footer"></slot>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import { scMq } from '~/assets/js/utils'

require('~/plugins/jquery');

require('datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables');
require('datatables.net-responsive');
require('datatables.net-select');
require('./dataTables.uikit');
require('./dataTables.responsive.uikit');

export default {
    name: 'Datatable',
    props: {
        data: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => [],
            required: true
        },
        options: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => {}
        },
        id: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        buttons: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        autoWidth: Boolean,
        tableClass: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        customEvents: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => []
        }
    },
    data: () => ({
        $dt: null
    }),
    computed: {
        dtData () {
            return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data))
        },
        headers () {
            let names = [];
            Object.keys(this.data[0]).map(k => {
                let name = k.replace(/_/g, ' ');
                names.push(name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1))
            });
            return names
        },
        columns () {
            let columns = [];
            Object.keys(this.data[0]).map(k => {
                columns.push({
                    data: k
                })
            });
            return columns;
        },
        ...mapState([
            'vxSidebarMainExpanded'
        ])
    },
    watch: {
        dtData (newVal, oldVal) {
            const newLength = newVal.length;
            const oldLength = oldVal.length;
            const newIds = newVal.map(k => {
                return k.id
            });
            const oldIds = oldVal.map(k => {
                return k.id
            });
            if(newLength > oldLength) {
                let uniq = newIds.filter(k => {
                    return !oldIds.includes(k)
                });
                if (uniq.length) {
                    const newEl = newVal.filter(obj => {
                        return obj.id === uniq[0]
                    });
                    this.$dt.row.add(newEl[0]).draw('full-hold');
                }
            } else {
                let uniq = oldIds.filter(k => {
                    return !newIds.includes(k)
                });
                if (uniq.length) {
                    this.$dt.row(':eq('+ uniq[0] +')').remove().draw('full-hold')
                }
            }
        },
        vxSidebarMainExpanded () {
            if(scMq.mediumMin()) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#' + this.id).resize()
                }, 300);
            }
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        const self = this;

        if(self.buttons) {
            const pdfMake = require('~/assets/js/vendor/pdfmake/pdfmake');
            const pdfFonts =require('~/assets/js/vendor/pdfmake/vfs_fonts');
            pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
            window.JSZip = require("~/assets/js/vendor/jszip");
            require('datatables.net-buttons');
            require('datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5');
            require('datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print');
        }
        let _options = {
            data: self.data,
            columns: self.columns,
            responsive: true,
            "initComplete" (settings, json) {
                self.$dt = this.api();
                self.$emit('initComplete');
            }
        };
        const options = $.extend(_options, self.options);
        if(options.responsive === 'responsiveModal') {
            _options.responsive = {
                details:  {
                    display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal({
                        header (row) {
                            return 'Details for row ' + (parseInt(row[0]) + 1);
                        }
                    }),
                    renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll({
                        tableClass: 'table'
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        $('#' + this.id).DataTable(options);
        if(this.customEvents.length) {
            this.customEvents.forEach(event => {
                this.$dt.on(event.name, event.function)
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to resolve this?